# Can I change my 205/60r16 tires with 205/55r16 tires?

Tags: tires, car

I am changing my seasonal tire to winter tires. My seasonal tires are size 205/60r16. Is it okay to change them with 205/55r16 sized tires?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It will have a slightly lower sidewall height, but should work fine.

Just for completeness:

For a 205/55r16 tire, the numbers mean:

- 205 - width of the tire in mm. On some wheels, you can go 5-10mm (approximately) over without a problem. However, it's good practice to stay with the exact with of the stock tire
- 55 - height of the sidewall as a percentage of the width. (AKA, aspect ratio.)
- 16 - diameter of the wheel in inches.

If your width (205mm) and diameter (16") match the tires that came on the car, you won't have fitment issues. However, a lower profile (sidewall height) tire may lead to a rougher ride.

See also [Understanding Tire Sizes](http://www.justtires.com/content/content.jsp?pageName=TireSize)

Comment: So what is the limit of what i can replace my tire size? what i mean is how low or high i could go? for example can i put on a 215/60/16?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will be completely fine, in fact 205/55/16 are the most common 16" tires.